# How to redirect destination IP on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, networking, routing, nat, redirection

I have a windows application (not browser-based and doesn't use DNS so no hosts file remapping) that has an external TCP destination IP at ex. `147.123.456.789 : 12345` and I want to redirect the traffic to a proxy server that is on my local network and listening on `10.0.1.22 : 12345`. I have tried using `route add 147.123.456.789 mask 255.255.255.255 10.0.1.22` However this does not do what I want as my proxy does not accept the connection, however my connection to `147.123.456.789` is interrupted, where is the traffic going, wire-shark shows it failing to send to `147.123.456.789`? I have used `Test-NetConnection 10.0.1.22 -p 12345` to verify that my proxy server is indeed working, but when I use `Test-NetConnection 147.123.456.789 -p 12345` the connection fails with the route added. I read from similar posts that routing does not do NAT, how and where would I implement this if i need it? As well i'm confused as to whether my proxy should be listening on its own IP `10.0.1.22` or `147.123.456.789` since routing doesn't do NAT. Also I saw another post recommending 3proxy should I be using this instead? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Wouldnt you just tell the Windows application the proxy address and tell the proxy the real external address?  Why the redirect effort?  Also, that netmask probably won't get you anywhere... 255.255.255.255 is the broadcast mask.

Comment: @mikem Yes that is what i'm trying to do, and my proxy is pointing to the real external address, but question is how to point the windows application to the proxy. To my understanding, the netmask of `255.255.255.255` means to match `147.123.456.789` exactly and not allow for a range of IPS to be routed as I only want to route this single connection to the proxy.What is the correct netmask for a single destination Ip? As in this link says that `255.255.255.255` is used for point to point links [link](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/netmask-ref.html)

Comment: If the proxy's address is 10.0.1.22 then that's what you would tell the application it's destination is.  Your app points to the proxy at 10.0.1.22 and the proxy points to the destination at 147.123.456.789.  If this is a browser-based app, then just set it in your browser proxy settings and point it to the proxy.